# Flume RpcClient Connection Pooling

Tags: java, apache, rpc, flume, flume-ng

Am using `Apache Flume` to pass events between my source and sink. I use `Avro` protocol. I am passing multiple events via `RpcClient`, and I have faced an issue that, When i pass more number of events, the channel goes offline and it shows connection error. Is there anyway to create pooled connection so that it stays active forever.?